# Passing data from db into Highcharts in Rails 3.x

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm a rails noob, and trying to figure out how to graph some data in a  database using high charts. I have the following code for the chart:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function() {
                new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: "pdd_graph"
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Percent Depth Dose"
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "datetime"
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        max: 1.4,
                        min: 1.2,
                        title: {
                            text: "measmt"
                        }               
                    },
                    series: [{
                        pointStart: <%= 12.months.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
                        data: <%= (12.months.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |test_date| @pdd.field_5x5 } %>,
                        name: '5cm X 5cm Field'             
                    }]

                });
            });

        </script>
```

I want to graph the columns test_date and field_5x5 from a table called pdd . I'm just having a hard time with the proper syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your post while researching an issue of my own. You may need to add `.inspect` on the end of your `data: <%= (12.months.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |test_date| @pdd.field_5x5 } %>,` line. I would like to claim credit for this wisdom but I picked it up from Ryan's [Railscast on Highcharts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts?view=asciicast)

Another thing I did was move that logic into my controller, assign it to a var and then pass the var along... that is not going well.